# Access to Outer class from inner class StackofStacks<T>

Tags: java, class, stack, this

I want to create a Class StacksofStacks, and every stack is made of integers. By now, my code looks like this:

```
class StacksOfStacks<Stack>{
  Stack<Integer> topStack;
  Stack<Integer> nextStack;
  public StacksOfStacks(){
    topStack = null;
  }
  public StacksOfStacks(Stack<Integer> topStack){
    this.topStack = topStack;
  }
  public class Stack<Integer>{
    int size;
    int maxSize;
    int top;
    public Stack(int top, int maxSize){
      this.top = top;
      this.size = 1;
      this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }
    public void push(int data){
      if(size == maxSize){
        Stack<Integer> newStack = new Stack<Integer>(data, maxSize); //Create new stack
        Stack<Integer> oldStack = StacksOfStacks.this.topStack; //Error
        // some code
      }
      //some code
    }
  }
```

The error occurs when I try to access to the outer class StackOfStacks from the inner class Stack (it is marked as //Error). What I am trying to do is to assign to a Stack called oldStack the topStack of my StackofStacks. In other similar questions I have read that if for example I have an outer class Outer, then I should be able to access to it using:

```
Outer.this.variable
```

This works is my outer class is defined as:

```
class Outer{
//code
}
```

Now I have something that looks like:

```
class Outer<T>{
//code
}
```

Anyway, the error the I get compiling is:

```
StacksOfStacks.java:22: error: incompatible types: StacksOfStacks<Stack>.Stack<java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to StacksOfStacks<Stack>.Stack<Integer>
        Stack<Integer> oldStack = StacksOfStacks.this.topStack; //Error
                                                     ^
  where Stack,Integer are type-variables:
    Stack extends Object declared in class StacksOfStacks
    Integer extends Object declared in class StacksOfStacks.Stack
1 error
```

Comment: Your error does not match the code you have pasted. The error does not have `this`, yet the code you pasted does.

Comment: sorry, corrected

Comment: `public class Stack<Integer>` - please explain.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer would be to get rid of the generics here, because they are not adding anything and are in fact obscuring the problem. The real problem is that `Integer` is being used as both a type and a generic type name. I've rewritten your code, replacing the generics with abbreviated forms to better illustrate the issue:

```
class StacksOfStacks<S>{
  Stack<Integer> topStack;
  Stack<Integer> nextStack;
  public StacksOfStacks(){
    topStack = null;
  }
  public StacksOfStacks(Stack<Integer> topStack){
    this.topStack = topStack;
  }
  public class Stack<I>{
    int size;
    int maxSize;
    int top;
    public Stack(int top, int maxSize){
      this.top = top;
      this.size = 1;
      this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }
    public void push(int data){
      if(size == maxSize){
        Stack<I> newStack = new Stack<I>(data, maxSize); //Create new stack
        Stack<I> oldStack = StacksOfStacks.this.topStack; //Error
        // some code
      }
      //some code
    }
  }
```

Because you had declared `class Stack<Integer>` within the context of the `Stack` declaration, `Integer` no longer refers to `java.lang.Integer` (barring specific circumstances), but the parameterized type.